# WCF Service Method Name in IIS Log

Tags: wcf, iis, logging

Can the IIS logs be configured to output the name of the method called for a WCF service?

Right now the logs show only the name of the svc file.

Current log:

> /myservice.svc

I would like it to show:

> /myservice.svc/mymethod

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way to have the IIS standard logging log the method name called on a service. It only registers the page serviced.

You can however enable WCF logging to produce an svclog file that does give complete insight in method invocations and WCF service operations. For details, look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx.

Might that be acceptable?